# In a dockerfile, what is the purpose of "#APT::Get::Install-Recommends"?

Tags: command-line, apt

Inside a Dockerfile I have the lines:

```
RUN echo '#APT::Get::Install-Recommends "0";' >/etc/apt/preferences.d/99recommends
RUN echo '#APT::Get::Install-Suggests "0";' >>/etc/apt/preferences.d/99recommends
```

I just want to know what these two lines do.

Comment: I suppose nothing significant as there is a hashtag (#) in the beginning of lines added to the file.

Comment: The hashtag makes the comment irrelelvant, but it's probably done that way so you can *change* configurations in the dockerfile by removing the hashmark at the beginning

Comment: Those lines look more like they would belong in an `apt.conf.d` file than in an apt `preferences.d` file though?